# declaration and definition

Tags: c

Still confused with declaration and definition in term of C:
if a header file is like:

```
#ifndef _BASIC_H_
#define _BASIC_H_

void test();
extern int i; //define or declare
#endif
```

and two source file f1.c and f2.c contain this header, then one source file need to define the variable "i".

but if the header file is like:

```
#ifndef _BASIC_H_
#define _BASIC_H_

void test();
int i; //define or declare
#endif
```

and two source files f1.c and f2.c, contain this header without define the variable "i" in any file, it still goes through when I use the variable.
my questions is when the variable is defined.

Thanks

Comment: [This answers the same question for C++.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1410563/what-is-the-difference-between-a-definition-and-a-declaration/1410632#1410632) There are differences between C and C++, but for what you ask they don't apply.

Comment: Note that `void test();` is not the same as `void test(void);`. The second one will catch errors where you call `test(foo);` at compile time.

Answer (score 8):

Defining a variable is when you allocate memory for the storage and maybe assign it a value. Declaring is when you state that a variable with a specific name and type exist, but memory has been allocated for it already.

The use of the `extern` keyword means that you are declaring the variable but not defining it.

In terms of your specific question, your first example is declaring and your second answer is defining.

Comment: I pretty much just summarized The C Programming Language's material on the matter. Thanks, though.

Comment: Note that '`int i;`' gives a definition of the variable.  The strict reading of the C standard says that if more than one file includes that header, then you will get multiple definitions for `i`, and the link phase of the compilation will fail.  Appendix J (§J.5.11), gives a 'common extension' as: **Multiple external definitions**
There may be more than one external definition for the identifier of an object, with or
without the explicit use of the keyword `extern`; if the definitions disagree, or more than
one is initialized, the behavior is undefined (6.9.2).

Comment: How is int i in 2nd case definition?? Is it due to the fact that it gets a garbage value; which is a defination??